# Equation solver/parser

Tags: ios, swift, math, equation, solver

I have an app that solves physics problems based on given knowns and unknowns .. but it does it the wrong way..

let's say we have this equation ( d = v * t )
We have here three variables .. the way I did it is like this

```
let v = 10
let t = 5
let d = nil

let result = Double()


if d == nil && v != nil && t != nil {
    result = v * t

}if v == nil && d != nil && t != nil {
    result = d / t

}if t == nil && v != nil && d != nil {
    result = d / v

}else{
    result = nil
}

print(result) // "50"
```

obviously it's a headache .. this is only a small equation with three vars.. what if I had 20 equations each has 5 vars.. it would be very exhausting to type.. So I'm wondering if there is a way to just type the equation and call .solve or something .. something like this

```
let equation = "d = v * t"
let knowns = [d:20,v:50]
let result = equation.solve(usingKnowns: knowns)
print(result) // "Optional(t = 0.4)"
```

Thanks in advance,
Any help would be really great

Comment: You might want to look at symbolic algebra libraries for Swift, such as [this](https://github.com/typelift/Algebra). If that is not what you want, search for tutorials on **recursive descent parsing**.

Comment: You could have a look at [`NSExpression`](https://nshipster.com/nsexpression/) and decide if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is to see what variable is unknown, supose you have X variables and you always get X-1 variables known and 1 unknown you don't really need to check if the knowns variables are != nil.

Other possibility is the one I recommend you:

```
func resolve(a: Double?, b: Double?, c: Double?)-> Double{
    //Default value
    var result: Double = 0.0
    //a missing
    if let b = b, let c = c{
        result = b*c
    }
    //b missing
    if let a = a, let b = b{
        result = a/b
    }
    //c missing
    if let a = a, let c = c{
        result = a/c
    }
    return result
}
```

In this case you have a single call with the 3 parameters, all of them optionals, so if you try a "if let" with 2 o them simultaneously and it works, it means the other one is the unknow variable.

This is the "cleanest" solution I can think of.

Comment: You could simplify using a `switch`… e.g `switch (v, t, d) {
    case let (v?, t?, nil):
        return v * t` etc. But it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but it doesn't solve the issue, as I have to write dozens of functions like that. What I am looking for is writing the equation and call a generator or sth that can give me the answer right back if it's existed.. without doing the IFs or SWITCHs